Why math is hard to understand or explain in reverse
Three people go into a restaurant and each of us has \$10. So we start with \$30.
The bill comes to \$25 which means there is \$5 left over. Out of that \$5 we each take back \$1 (which would be \$3 altogether), which leaves \$2 that we leave for a tip.
If we each took \$1 back that means we each only spent \$9 initially instead of 10. Now, 9 * 3 is 27, plus the 2 is 29. We started with \$30 so where did that other dollar go?

I've never understood this - I still don't know if I ever will but I'm just putting it out there to see if anyone else has found a way to understand it. I think it has been mentioned that it comes down to something like a decimal point (or something of that sort) but if it does then who spent more and how do we decide that? Just a little mind-boggle for the day :)


Welcome to Puzzling :) This question is similar to: Where has the last dollar gone?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. (PS This type of problem is often known as the 'Missing dollar riddle' - there's a page on Wikpedia that might help...)

The original 30 is no longer relevant, and each 9 includes the tip. So 9 * 3 = 27 minus the tip is 25. I think there is a similar deception that con-men play when asking for change of a banknote, and then change their mind about what they want part way through.

Also, this isn't "hard to explain" or "hard to understand". Someone is deliberately tricking you by acting like it's normal to add something in a place where you should subtract it, and comparing to an irrelevant amount, in order to make you feel like you "don't get it".
